# How to create an inline keyboard with multiple rows in telegrambot using sgcWebSockets api telegram?

Tags: c++, c++builder, telegram-api

How can I create an inline keyboard with several buttons, one per row?

like:

```
inlineBtn1
inlineBtn2
inlineBtn3
...
```

not:

```
inlineBtn1  inlineBtn2  inlineBtn3 ...
```

I did it as in the example, but this is not the result I need, all the buttons are in one line

```
//my code
TsgcTelegramReplyMarkupInlineKeyboard *oReplyMarkup = new TsgcTelegramReplyMarkupInlineKeyboard();

oReplyMarkup->AddButtonTypeCallback("Hello", "1");
oReplyMarkup->AddButtonTypeCallback("Bye", "2");

TelegramMain->SendTextMessage("1234", "My message with buttons", oReplyMarkup);
```